# Regex Only match numbers Php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code

```
if (preg_match('/[^1-9]/', $single )){
   print_r($single."\n");
}
```

My Input is:

```
170
111.111.111.111.in-addr.
dns.names.com
```

My Regex matches all of the Input, but i want to only have the 170. Im not familiar.

Comment: does your input has multiple line feeds?

Comment: nope there are no empty lines

Comment: does it look like `170 111.111.111.111.in-addr.dns.names.com` ?

Comment: no: after 170 \n, after 111.111.111.111.in-addr.\n

Comment: @Pranav C Balan both not working :(

Comment: @mk2015  `/^\d+/` or `/\d+(?=\n)/` or ``/\d+(?!\.)/``

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the first number positioned anywhere in your string, you can use this expression:
`/(?:^|\s+)(\d+)(?:\s+|\n+|$)/`

In your list, it will only match `170`, as you asked.

If your string may contain several numbers you want to select, specify the `g` (global) modifier like this: `/(?:^|\s+)(\d+)(?:\s+|\n+|$)/g`

[Example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gH2rA5/2)

> I added 2 test strings in the case where your string has not line-feed or doesn't start with a number.

Comment: Good practice to always test the regular expression against your input, outside your application. This way you know that the regexp works before using it, as part of your code. The website (regex101) provided by @Niitaku is a great resource for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing $single which is your text that's why you see this text on screen. If you want to see only 170, you must print what was matched:

```
$single = "170

111.111.111.111.in-addr.

dns.names.com";
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)\s/', $single, $matches )){
   print_r($matches[1]."\n");
}
```

And output is: 170 - as you wanted